# Insert an equation (equation editor) in Excel using cell values as variables

Tags: excel, cell, equations

I would like to insert an equation in Excel using the equation editor. However I would like to use values of specific cells as variables for the equation.

Consider this over-simplistic example: X + Y = Z

I would like to ensure that X would show the value of cell A1, Y would show the value of B2 and Z the value of C2.

I can create the Excel function on the background without any issues. But what I want to do here is display the notation of the equation in a nice format.

Is this possible at all?

Regards,
P.

Comment: The idea here was that when I changed the value of the cells in the Excel sheet, the formula **in the equation editor** would get updated to reflect those changes. This is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to update this for completeness sake. I spoke with team members of the Excel dev team and what I was trying to achieve is not supported. They like the idea though, and they will "consider it for a future version of Excel" (whatever that means). :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right you could just concatenate it as a string.

```
= A1 & " + " & B2 & " = " & C2
```

Comment: Actually that is not it. This is just an Excel function. I am talking about using the Equation Editor to make proper notations like fractions, radicals, integrals, operators like summations and products, matrices, etc. What I want to do is insert cell values in such equations.